# How to interpolate on categorical data

Tags: string, matlab, interpolation, string-interpolation, categorical-data

I need to interpolate the data. For float numbers I normally use

```
interp1(given_time,given_data,uniform_time)
```

However, in this case my `given_data` is a string array cell:

```
time=[1,5,18,30,40,42,47,54,64]

season=[{'winter'},{'winter'},{'winter'}, {'spring'}, {'spring'}, {'spring'}, {'summer'}, {'summer'}, {'summer'} ]

uniform_time=1:5:64

uniform_season= ????
```

Each cell of output must be a string according to the nearest value of `uniform_time`

How to implement it in matlab?

In case `uniform_time(i)` is exactly between `time(j)` and `time(k)`, either value of `season(j)` or `season(k)` is acceptable.

In the case above, I expect to get:

```
uniform_season= [{'winter'}, {'winter'}, {'winter'}, {'winter'}, {'winter'}, {'spring'}, {'spring'}, {'spring'}, {'spring/summer'}, {'summer'}, {'summer'}, {'summer'}, {'summer'}]
```

by `{'spring/summer'}` I mean either `{'spring'}` or `{'summer'}` but not both like `{'spring/summer'}`.

I calculated it according to this table:

```
new data: 1 6   11  16  21  26  31  36  41  46  51  56  61
closest old data: 1 5   18  18  18  30  30  40  41/42   47  54  54  64
string of old data: 'winter'    'winter'    'winter'    'winter'    'winter'    'spring'    'spring'    'spring'    spring/summer'  'summer'    'summer'    'summer'    'summer'
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Try replace season with an index vector of numbers like `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]` (the other outputs of `unique` will help) and then just use `interp1` with the nearest neighbour flag and use the result to index back into the first output from `unique`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
%// Inputs:
time=[1,5,18,30,40,42,47,54,64]
season=[{'winter'},{'winter'},{'winter'}, {'spring'}, {'spring'}, {'spring'}, {'summer'}, {'summer'}, {'summer'} ]
uniform_time=1:5:64

%// Change season to an ordinal list
[season_unique,~,season_int] = unique(season, 'stable')
idx = interp1(time, season_int, uniform_time, 'nearest-neighbour') %// Good chance you'll want to add the 'extrap' flag here as well
season_unique(idx)
```

Comment: Very nice.. Didn't knew `nearest-neighbour` existed. :) I guess its not too late to know :P +1